# Same data object for every client PHP

Tags: php, caching

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

How to prevent executing query to database every time a new client connects when it's going to be same $result every time?
I have tried using singleton class but it's not working cause static variable have local scope I guess.
I'm using PHP8 MySQL8.

Comment: You're trying to _cache_!? Either internally, cache database query results in memcache or redis or something like that? Or cache the entire HTTP/HTML response with a caching proxy in front of your PHP?

Comment: This sounds like it's potentially a non-issue. That's what web apps do...different users get another copy of your page. As above, you _could_ try caching if the database data changes very infrequently, I guess. But that's a change to your system architecture, it's not something you achieve just by tweaking your PHP a bit.

Comment: If a variable is going to be the same every time, then it is a constant.

Comment: @deceze won't the variable containing memcache result get new instance for every client? Also memcache not available for php8

Comment: Every single request, every single invocation of your PHP script is a completely new, independent instance with no shared variables of any other instances. Maybe this is the main thing you're missing here…?

Comment: @deceze so how do I reduce the number of calls to the sql database?

Comment: Byyyyyy not calling your SQL database every time and instead _caching the data_ elsewhere; like memcache, redis, a caching HTTP proxy etc…